# why loop did not execute else

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
path1=r'/Users/Desktop/forks.csv'
path2=r'/Users/Desktop/forks1.csv'
outdata=[]
count=0
i=0
with open(path1,'rb') as input:
reader=csv.reader(input)
for row in reader:
    if i==0:
        i=i+1
        outdata.append(row)
        continue
    if int(row[5])>0:
        row.append(1)
        outdata.append(row)
        count=count+1
        print count
    else: 
        row.append(0)
        outdata.append(row)
        count=count+1
print count
with open (path2,'wb') as output:
  writer=csv.writer(output,delimiter=',')
  writer.writerows(outdata)
```

I have a large table, I want to add a column with boolean value to each row. If the column 6 is lager than 0, it should be 1. if is 0, it should be zero. but the loop stop at which

```
58542
58543
58544
58545
58546
58547
58548
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Documents/workspace/datamining/opensource/label.py", line 18, in <module>
if int(row[5])>0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The information in the table is below, which means the else loop did not execute. I test in the small table,the code works.I don't know why it cannot work in large dataset?

---

```
58547                1
58548                1
58549                0
58550                0
```

---

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. Please paste a correct version. Note: you should prefer spaces for indentation instead of tabs. In this way when you paste the code here on SO the indentation wont be messed up for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You're passing an empty value as an argument to `int`. `int` obviously cannot convert an empty value to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like column 6 is blank (empty) rather than containing a string which can be converted to an integer. The `else` block isn't being executed because an exception is raised instead. Try:

```
if row[5] and int(row[5])>0:
```

to check for empty `row[5]` before converting it to an `int`. The empty string, `''` evaluates to `False` in this comparison and so should trigger the `else` block.